# Android Studio How to add a module

Tags: android-studio

I think I made a huge mistake. I deleted the default module in the Project Structure of my Android Studio Project. Now when I try to rebuild my project it says that it can't find the AndroidManifest.xml

What do I have to do get my module back?
Which options do I have to set for the module?

Comment: What is that? If you mean Version Control. I didn't set that up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better to re-import or recreate the module.

CTRL-Z works, but I guess your beyond that point.

An other solution would be to write (by hand) all the config files (settings.gradle & build.gradle)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm beyond that point. Would it work if I just made a new project and copied all (src) files from the old project into the new one?

Comment: Yes. Since src has no info on how the project is setup, it would work.

Comment: It worked the only problem is that it is now throwing a NullPointerException where it didn't before. :(